# Trimming a string in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am trimming a string data type that has a value of \t in C# .NET 3.5. I have used the method .SubString() and converted it on a char data type but still it won't work.

It returns "\" as a char.

I wanted to get the value of "\t" instead of \t or "\";

Here's my code:

```
string sample = "\\t";

char val = Convert.ToChar(sample.Substring(0, 1));
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear what you're actually trying to do. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: What result are you expecting?  You have a two-character string:  "\" and "t", and you are getting the substring of the first character, which is "\".

Comment: What are you trying to get as the end result?

Comment: I'm sorry for not identifying what I wanted to achieve. I've already modified my question. I wanted to say that the stackoverflow text editor automatically makes the \\t into "\t" even I've type it on a correct manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"\\t"` specifies a backslash (`\\`) followed by a t (`t`). Since `Substring(0, 1)` returns the first character, it would return the backslash.

Comment: Actually, it specifies a backslash (`\\\`) followed by a literal t.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `"\\t"`, just use `"\t"`, with one slash.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [string literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx) to reduce this confusion.

```
string a = "hello \t world";   // hello     world
string b = @"hello \t world";  // hello \t world
```

Answer (score 0):

It kind of sounds like you are trying to remove occurrences of tabs (`\t`) from a string? If that's the case, you can use the Trim function: `s.Trim('\t')`.

There's also TrimStart and TrimEnd, to remove from the start only or from the end only. If you want to remove all occurrences of tabs from the string, you can do `s = s.Replace("\t",string.Empty)`.